# I want to make a link from external place (Different from Google Drive) to an on dailly based creating file in Google Drive (Different FileID)

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, external, drive

I create every day a report in PDF format on Google Drive with Google Appscript. This works fine.

I will have a link from my Iphone to this report and that is also possible.

The problem is that de PDF report that I created every day, has a different FileID, so the link on my phone don't work the next day.

Is there a solution. Is it possible to work with different versions of PDF files with programming with AppScript (API's)? Or is there an other workaround?

Wait for an answer,
Danny

Comment: it looks as if you made copy and paste errors while making the question. Can you fix that?